# r-markdown: German quotation marks for pdf_documents

Tags: r, localization, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I coudln't find out how to use the "lang: de" option ([link](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex_options)) properly. That is, while tables are correctly named "Tabelle", the following settings:

```
---
title: "German quotation marks"
author: "will"
date: "24 Jänner 2018"
output: pdf_document
---

"Das ist sehr schön", sagte sie.
```

Produce this output:

[image]

whereas the following is needed:

[image]

Comment: Type Alt-CTRL + V for „ and Alt-CTRL + B for “ (on Linux)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following [Tobi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150958/136969) we can define language and use latex package `csquotes`.

```
---
title: "German quotation marks"
author: "will"
date: "24 Jänner 2018"
output: pdf_document
lang: de
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{csquotes}
---

"Das ist sehr schön", sagte sie.
```

### *Yields:*

[image]