# r-markdown: German quotation marks break bold text in HTML document

Tags: r, localization, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

When German quotation marks („ and “ or HTML code `&bdquo;` and `&ldquo;`, see https://unicode-table.com/de/201E/ and https://unicode-table.com/de/201C/) are in between bold text markers `**...**`, then pandoc does not render the text bold when I knit in RStudio. Even worse, the `**`s are printed verbatim in the HTML document.

Example:

```
---
output: html_document
lang: de
---

This is a **„Test“**.

Another **&bdquo;Test&ldquo;**.

This **"just works"**.
```

Result:

[image: German quotation marks break the bold text]

Are there any pandoc options or workarounds for solving this problem?

Note that a similar question was answered for PDF output in [r-markdown: German quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427353/r-markdown-german-quotation-marks). But I need HTML output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue tracking input of localized quotes is https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/661.

Meanwhile, I recommend using non-typographic quotes (`"`) and for HTML-output use the `--html-q-tags` option and [some CSS, like](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/quotes):

```
q {
  quotes: '„' '“';
}
```

Comment: Works and is slightly more comfortable, because I only have to use sed once before running pandoc, not every time after I ran pandoc as well. When using R Markdown, one can set the extra pandoc option via `pandoc_args: "--html-q-tags"` within the `output: html_document:` block of the YAML header. The CSS can be added in the markdown document within a `<style></style>` tag.

Comment: @sgrubsmyon @mb21 : But what can we do with `output: github_document`? Unfortunately CSS can't be used there... (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51956450/3915051).

Answer (score 0):

My workaround: I made use of the command line tool `sed` and regular expressions:

First, modify the .Rmd (or .md) file and replace all the German typographic quotation marks with standard quotation marks: (WARNING: commands change the file inplace!)

```
sed -i 's/„/"/g' mydocument.Rmd
sed -i 's/“/"/g' mydocument.Rmd
```

Knit the document (or convert it to HTML with pandoc).

Then, replace all the English typographic quotation marks with German ones:

```
sed -i "s/“/„/g" mydocument.html
sed -i "s/”/“/g" mydocument.html
```

Comment: Post-knit treatment (using sed) is not practical as you has to do it manually each time (or write some function to take care it of it). Thus, I prefer the CSS solution.