# Germany quotation marks broken in tinytex/rmarkdown

Tags: localization, r-markdown, tex, tinytex

*What I want:*

I'd like to have German quotation marks in my TeX-PDF via rmarkdown and tinytex on MacOS (Catalina). See for example:

[image]

*The problem:*

It used to work following the guidelines [as proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427353/r-markdown-german-quotation-marks). But now, it stopped working. I only get English quotation marks, but *not* German ones:

[image]

*What I tried, without success*:

- I updated my R packages
- I updated TeX packages
- I checked that the TeX package "csquotes" is installed
- I changed the language from "de" to "de-De"

*R-Code*:

```
---
title: "German quotation marks"
output: pdf_document
---

"Das ist sehr schön", sagte sie.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The R Markdown package used to provide its own template, which used `csquotes.sty`. Nowadays the default `pandoc` template is used, which does not seem to use `csquotes`. You can call for it manually, though:

```
---
title: "German quotation marks"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        keep_tex: yes
lang: de-DE
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{csquotes}
---

"Das ist sehr schön", sagte sie.
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. The way that you presented is the right way. However, I forget to put to the code that I did use csquotes. Even with csquotes, it does not work (or rather, stopped working some time ago for reasons unclear to me). For clarity, I will accept and close this issue and open a new one where I include csquotes.

Comment: According to https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf, you need to add also `csquotes: true` to the frontmatter.