# Germany quotation marks broken in tinytex/rmarkdown - even when using package `csquotes`

Tags: r, localization, r-markdown, quotes, tinytex

*What I want:*

I'd like to have German quotation marks in my TeX-PDF via rmarkdown and tinytex on MacOS (Catalina). See for example:

[image]

*The problem:*

It used to work following the guidelines [as proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427353/r-markdown-german-quotation-marks). But now, it stopped working. I only get English quotation marks, but *not* German ones:

[image]

*What I tried, without success*:

- I updated my R packages
- I updated TeX packages
- I checked that the TeX package "csquotes" is installed
- I changed the language from "de" to "de-De"

*R-Code*:

```
---
title: "German quotation marks"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        keep_tex: yes
lang: de-DE
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{csquotes}
---

"Das ist sehr schön", sagte sie.
```

*sessionInfo:*

- R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
- Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
- Running under: macOS  10.15.2
- tinytex v0.18
- TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019)

```
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.0  htmltools_0.4.0 tools_3.6.0     yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.3     
 [6] rmarkdown_2.0   knitr_1.26      xfun_0.11       digest_0.6.23   packrat_0.5.0  
[11] rlang_0.4.2     evaluate_0.14
```

**EDIT**

Based on the @RalfStubner's suggestion below, here's the minimal reproducible version of the TeX-File that was compiled by the code above:

```
\documentclass[
  ngerman,
]{article}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,main=ngerman]{babel}


\title{German quotation marks}
\author{}
\date{\vspace{-2.5em}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

``Das ist sehr schön'', sagte sie.

\end{document}
```

The code did compile - but the problem remained (no German quotes, only English quotes):

[image]

Comment: With `keep-tex: yes` you get a `.tex` file you can inspect independently: 1. Verify that compiling the `.tex` reproduces the issue. 2. Produce a [mre] by removing anything from the `.tex` file that is not needed to reproduce the issue. 3. [Edit] your question to include the minimal `.tex`.

Comment: BTW, this reduction makes sense only if the bare minimum for a working solution is present in the `.tex` file: packages `babel` and `csquotes` as well as option `ngerman`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NMarkgraf I just learned that this solution does work:

```
---
title: "German quotation marks"
output: 
    pdf_document:
        keep_tex: yes
lang: de-DE
csquotes: true  # THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE

header-includes:
    - \usepackage{csquotes}
---

"Das ist sehr schön", sagte sie.
```

So, the point was to add a YAML-variable `csquotes` with value `yes`.

Comment: Interesting. Which `pandoc` version do you use? Do you sill need the `header-includes`? For me the `csquotes: true` header does nothing.

Comment: It's strange, and new to me too. pandoc version: `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()
[1] ‘2.9.1’`. Not 100% convinced though which version RStudio actually draws upon, as RStudio comes shipped with some pandoc in some version.

Comment: The version found this way is the version used for processing. This is considerably newer than the version I am using (2.5), which probably explains the different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this issue as well. The YAML description [states](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html%23raw-tex) that

> if your LaTeX template or any included header file call for the [csquotes] package, pandoc will detect this automatically and use \enquote{...} for quoted text.

So you actually only need to add

```
csquotes: true  # THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE
```

There's no need to add

```
    - \usepackage{csquotes}
```

at least this works for me.